# Filtering a large list to remove objects in a secondary list

Tags: c#, linq

I'm implementing some code to sort through the ticketmaster categories API call so that I only store the objects that contains music categories.

The API returns a huge list. I have a list of ints containing the categories I want to keep. I could go through the entire list as a loop but I will be going through the list around 100 times to filter out what I want which seems very inefficient.

Is there a simple way with LINQ to do this?

Comment: You'd have to try to reduce the number of times you go through the list, linq or not - can you share why you currently go through it that many times?

Comment: Posting some code (classes, loops, etc) would be helpful

Comment: LINQ will still loop through the list. Just because you're not manually writing a `foreach`, does not mean that LINQ does not use a `foreach` internally. If you're looking for _code simplification_, LINQ is a good solution. If you're looking to _avoid looping_ (performance wise), then LINQ is not a solution (and I'm not sure what would be a solution, to be honest).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're a bit unclear with your question, but you can try with `Except` method

```
List<string> largeList = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" };
List<string> smallList = new List<string>() { "a", "b" };

var result = largeList.Except(smallList).ToList();
```

EDIT:
that will give you items that don't exist in small list (`c,` `d` and `e` in this example. Other solution can be, as Flater suggested in comment, that you want to get items that exist in small list (`a` and `b`). In that case, use `Intersect`

```
var result = largeList.Intersect(smallList).ToList();
```

Comment: I'm assuming OP wants the `Intersect(smallList)` (i.e the items that **exist** in `smallList`), as opposed to the `Except(smallList)` (i.e. the items that **do not exist** in `smallList`) From the question body: `"I have a list of ints containing the categories I want to keep"`

Comment: @Flater thanks for suggestion, I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a *large* list of filters, the trick is to use *hashing*: `O(1)` time complexity versus `O(N)` if you keep categories as a list ("...going through the list around 100 times to filter out..."):

```
  HashSet<int> CategoriesToKeep = new HashSet<int>(ListOfCategories);

  ...

  var filtered = initialList
    .Where(item => CategoriesToKeep.Contains(item.Category))
    .ToList(); // if you want to materialize
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something similar to:

```
var myCategories = .... //some enumeration of ints
var filteredInfo = GetTicketMasterCategoriesInfo().Where(
                       tm => myCategories.Contains(tm.Category));
```